# Reverse Proxy through HTTP Proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-proxy, tinyproxy

I am looking for a reverse-proxy that allows proxy chaining to http proxy.

The use case: I am inside a corporate network that is under a proxy. I want to build a reverse proxy that will act such that `http[s]://my.reverse.proxy` will response the content of `http[s]://facebook.com` (for example).

I tried to use NGINX to set the reverse proxy, but it's stuck on the corporate proxy. Is there any way for me to set an upstream proxy?

I managed to do it via Tinyproxy, but it does not support HTTPS requests.

The reverse proxy should support https as well.

Comment: Nginx is not meant for this use case. You would need a squid proxy server

Comment: WinGate will also do this, if you are looking on a Windows platform.